# How to build Microsoft Rocket in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, video, analysis, rocket

I’m setting up Microsoft rocket video analysis system in visual studio. The instructions were great up until the point where it simply says build the application. There is no menu item in visual studio that says build. I would like some help from somebody that has done this.

I looked every menu item in visual studio and searched the Internet for help with this problem. Also, I tried various things in the command prompt window.